# Distance using taxicab geometry: weird output

Tags: c, matrix

I was trying an algorithm based in a metric, called [taxicab metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). Then My objective was create a simple example, you have a simple 3x3 matrix and in the first position you have 1. From that you calculate the distance that the other positions are, like this:

1 2 3

2 3 4

3 4 5

For that I created the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main ()
{
int matrix[3][3]={1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, i, j;
for ( i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    for( j=0; j<3; j++)
        matrix[i][j]=  abs(i-1)+ abs (j-1)+1;//taxicab algorithm 
        printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]);//prints the matrix
        printf("\n");

 }
return 0;
}
```

However, the output is

0

0

3

I have no clue of why this is happening. Why does it print only the first column??? And why 1 became 0?

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax mistake, the second `for` loop has no brackets. This is ok for single line statements, but without brackets, `if, for, while, etc`, only apply to the first line after it (up to the semicolon). Add brackets to multiline `for` loops:

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = abs(i-1) + abs(j-1) + 1; //taxicab algorithm 
        printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]); //prints the matrix
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

In your code this was causing the print statements to not be called as often as you thought.

(I actually recommend always using brackets on all `for` loops, and most `if` statements for this reason)

Comment: Or for single statement for/if put it on the same line?

Comment: Should the printf come outside the second for?

Comment: @JustinMeiners now it prints always the same thing D: no matter where is the 1, actually, no matter the inicialization

Comment: it only prints

3 2 3

2 1 2

3 2 3

the one is always in the center @JustinMeiners

Comment: @Charlie maybe you don't want the -1 just do abs(i) + abs(j) + 1